# Quicksort using strings, median element strategy

Tags: c

I am trying to code a quicksort algorithm for the following structure, I want to sort the array alphabetically.

```
    typedef struct
{
  char *str; //string

} v_elemento;

/**
* this register has the array, a counter for the size and capacity.
*/
typedef struct
{
  /** size of vector */
  int tamanho;   

  /** capacity of the vetor */
  int capacidade;     

  /** array  */
  v_elemento* elementos;  
} vetor;
```

In order to choose the pivot I am using the three elements median strategy. However, it is not working properly... here's my code.

```
    void quick_sort(vetor* vec,int left,int right)
{
    int pivot,j,i,escolha_pivo;
    char* temp;

            if(left>=right)
            return;

            i=left;
            j=right;
            escolha_pivo=(left+right)/2; //middle element

            // pivot is the median of the three elements
            if(strcmp(vec->elementos[left].str,vec->elementos[right].str)<0){
                if(strcmp(vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str,vec->elementos[right].str)>=0){
                    temp=vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str;
                    vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str=vec->elementos[right].str;
                    vec->elementos[right].str=temp;

                }
                else if(strcmp(vec->elementos[left].str,vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str)>0){
                    temp=vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str;
                    vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str=vec->elementos[left].str;
                    vec->elementos[left].str=temp;
                }
            }
                 if(strcmp(vec->elementos[left].str,vec->elementos[right].str)>=0){
                    if(strcmp(vec->elementos[right].str,vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str)>=0){

                        temp=vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str;
                        vec->elementos[escolha_pivo].str=vec->elementos[right].str;
                        vec->elementos[right].str=temp;
                    }

            }
                pivot=escolha_pivo;
        }

//quicksort algorithm
            while(i<j){
                while(strcmp(vec->elementos[i].str,vec->elementos[pivot].str)<=0 && (i<right)){
                    i++;
                }
                while(strcmp(vec->elementos[j].str,vec->elementos[pivot].str)>0){
                    j--;
                }
                if(i<j){
                    temp=vec->elementos[i].str;
                    vec->elementos[i].str=vec->elementos[j].str;
                    vec->elementos[j].str=temp;
                }
            }
                temp=vec->elementos[pivot].str;
                vec->elementos[pivot].str=vec->elementos[j].str;
                vec->elementos[j].str=temp;
                quick_sort(vec,left,j-1);
                quick_sort(vec,j+1,right);

}
```

The code is working well if I force my pivot to be the left or the right element but we all know that's not the most efficient way possible so I think my quicksort algorithm is correct.

Sample:

Original array (it is huge, only gonna put a few elements):

```
Quercus rubra L.
Dicksonia antarctica
Prunus laurocerasus (L.)
Pinus bungeana Zuccarini
Abies koreana Wilson
Pieris japonica (Thunb.) D. Don.
Quercus coccifera L.
Calocedrus decurrens ((Torrey) Florin)
Podocarpus macrophyllus (Thunberg)
Dasylirion acrotrichum ((Schiede) Zucc.)
Picea orientalis (L.) Link.
Cedrus libani (A. Richard)
Crataegus monogyna Jacq.
Calliandra tweedii (Benth.)
Thujopsis dolobrata (Siebold & Zucc.)
Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
Quercus robur L.
Laburnum anagyroides (Medic.)
Portulacaria afra (Jacq)
Cryptomeria japonica (L. filius) D. Don
Carpinus betulus
Juniperus chinensis (L.)
Pieris japonica (Thunb.) D. Don.
Pyracantha coccinea M. J. Roem.
Cordyline australis (G.Forst.) Endl.
Deutzia crenata
Vaccinium corymbosum L.
Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
Bischofia javanica Blume
Deutzia crenata
Casuarina cristata (Miquel)
Laurus nobilis L.
Spiraea cantoniensis Lour
Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
Quercus suber L.
Dasylirion acrotrichum ((Schiede) Zucc.)
Viburnum opulus L.
Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
Spiraea japonica L. f.
Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Abies cephalonica Loudon
Picea pungens Engelmann
Picea sitchensis (Bongard) Carrere.
Populus x canadensis (Moench)
Camellia japonica (L.)
Abies nordmannQuercus rubra L.
Dicksonia antarctica
Prunus laurocerasus (L.)
Pinus bungeana Zuccarini
Abies koreana Wilson
Pieris japonica (Thunb.) D. Don.
Quercus coccifera L.
Calocedrus decurrens ((Torrey) Florin)
Podocarpus macrophyllus (Thunberg)
Dasylirion acrotrichum ((Schiede) Zucc.)
Picea orientalis (L.) Link.
Cedrus libani (A. Richard)
Crataegus monogyna Jacq.
Calliandra tweedii (Benth.)
Thujopsis dolobrata (Siebold & Zucc.)
Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
Quercus robur L.
Laburnum anagyroides (Medic.)
Portulacaria afra (Jacq)
Cryptomeria japonica (L. filius) D. Don
Carpinus betulus
Juniperus chinensis (L.)
Pieris japonica (Thunb.) D. Don.
Pyracantha coccinea M. J. Roem.
Cordyline australis (G.Forst.) Endl.
Deutzia crenata
Vaccinium corymbosum L.
Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
Bischofia javanica Blume
Deutzia crenata
Casuarina cristata (Miquel)
Laurus nobilis L.
Spiraea cantoniensis Lour
Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
Quercus suber L.
Dasylirion acrotrichum ((Schiede) Zucc.)
Viburnum opulus L.
Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
Spiraea japonica L. f.
Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Abies cephalonica Loudon
Picea pungens Engelmann
Picea sitchensis (Bongard) Carrere.
Populus x canadensis (Moench)
Camellia japonica (L.)
Abies nordmanniana (Steven) Spach 1841.
Aloe vera (L.) Burm.F.
Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
Cordyline australis (G.Forst.) Endl.
Cupressus lusitanica Miller
Araucaria angustifolia (Bertol.) Kuntze
Abies fraseri (Pursh) Poiret
Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
Cotoneaster salicifolius Franch.
Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Acer rubrum L.
Quercus robur L.
Deutzia crenata
Cercidiphyllum japonicum (Siebold & Zucc.)
Cercis siliquastrum L.
Jasminum officinalle (L.)
Ostrya carpinifolia Scop.
Pyracantha coccinea M. J. Roem.
Populus alba (L.)
Callistemon linearis (DC.)
Casuarina cristata (Miquel)
Spiraea cantoniensis Lour
Ginkgo biloba (L.)
Chaenomeles japonica (Thunb.) Lindl. Ex Spach
Tilia tomentosa Moench
Quercus suber L.
Chlorophytum comosum (Thunberg) Jacques
Pieris japonica (Thunb.) D. Don.
Cercidiphyllum japonicum (Siebold & Zucc.)
Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
Cupressus lusitanica Miller
Thuja plicata (D. Don)
Quercus coccifera L.
Acer palmatum Thunb.
Paulownia tomentosa (Thunb.) Steudel
Cupressus arizonica Greene
Pinus bungeana Zuccarini
Cercidiphyllum japonicum (Siebold & Zucc.)
Cupressus arizonica Greene
Mahonia aquifolium (L.)
Thuja plicata (D. Don)
Pinus contorta Douglas
Colletia spinosissima J. F. Gmel.
Paulownia tomentosa (Thunb.) Steudel
```

Using left and median as a pivot:

```
    Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
    Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
    Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
    Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
    Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
    Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
    Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
    Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
    Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
    Abies cephalonica Loudon
    Abies cephalonica Loudon
    Abies cephalonica Loudon
    Abies cilicica (Ant. & kotchy) Carriere
    Abies fraseri (Pursh) Poiret
    Abies fraseri (Pursh) Poiret
    Abies koreana Wilson
    Abies koreana Wilson
    Abies nordmanniana (Steven) Spach 1841.
    Abies nordmanniana (Steven) Spach 1841.
    Abies pinsapo Boisser
    Acacia nilotica (L.) Willd. ex Delile
    Acacia nilotica (L.) Willd. ex Delile
    Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
    Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
    Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
    Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
    Acacia verticillata (L'Her.) Willd.
    Acer buergerianum Miq.
    Acer japonicum Thunb.
    Acer negundo L.
    Acer palmatum Thunb.
    Acer palmatum Thunb.
    Acer pseudoplatanus L.
    Acer rubrum L.
    Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
    Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
    Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
    Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
    Agave americana (L.)
    Agave americana (L.)
    Aloe vera (L.) Burm.F.
    Aloe vera (L.) Burm.F.
    Aloe vera (L.) Burm.F.
    Araucaria angustifolia (Bertol.) Kuntze
    Araucaria angustifolia (Bertol.) Kuntze
    Arbutus xalapensis Kunth
    Arbutus xalapensis Kunth
    Bischofia javanica Blume
    Bischofia javanica Blume
    Bischofia javanica Blume
    Brugmansia sanguinea (Ruiz e Pav.) D. Don
    Brugmansia sanguinea (Ruiz e Pav.) D. Don
    Caesalpina spinosa (mol.) Kuntze
    Caesalpina spinosa (mol.) Kuntze
    Caesalpina spinosa (mol.) Kuntze
    Caesalpinia echinata (Lam.)
    Calliandra tweedii (Benth.)
    Calliandra tweedii (Benth.)
    Callistemon linearis (DC.)
    Callistemon linearis (DC.)
    Callistemon linearis (DC.)
    Callistemon linearis (DC.)
    Calocedrus decurrens ((Torrey) Florin)
    Calycanthus floridus (L.)
    Camellia japonica (L.)
    Carissa bispinosa ((L.) Desf. Ex Brenan)
    Carpinus betulus
    Carpinus betulus
    Carpinus betulus
    Carpinus japonica (Blume)
    Carpinus japonica (Blume)
    Castanea sativa (Mill.)
    Castanea sativa (Mill.)
    Casuarina cristata (Miquel)
    Casuarina cristata (Miquel)
    Casuarina cunnringhamiana (Miquel)
    Casuarina cunnringhamiana (Miquel)
    Casuarina cunnringhamiana (Miquel)
    Catalpa x erubescens
    Catalpa x erubescens
    Cedrus Atlantica ((Endlicher) Carriere)
    Cedrus libani (A. Richard)
    Cedrus libani (A. Richard)
    Cedrus libani (A. Richard)
    Celtis occidentalis (L.)
    Celtis occidentalis (L.)
    Celtis occidentalis (L.)
    Cephalotaxus harringtonia ((Forbes) Kock)
    Ceratonia siliqua (L.)
    Ceratonia siliqua (L.)
    Cercidiphyllum japonicum (Siebold & Zucc.)
    Cercidiphyllum japonicum (Siebold & Zucc.)
    Cercidiphyllum japonicum (Siebold & Zucc.)
    Cercis chinensis (Bunge)
    Cercis siliquastrum L.
    Cercis siliquastrum L.
    Cercis siliquastrum L.
    Cercis siliquastrum L.
    Chaenomeles japonica (Thunb.) Lindl. Ex Spach
    Chaenomeles japonica (Thunb.) Lindl. Ex Spach
    Chaenomeles japonica (Thunb.) Lindl. Ex Spach
    Chamaecyparis lawsoniana (A. Murray) Parlatore
    Chamaerops humilis (L.)
    Chlorophytum comosum (Thunberg) Jacques
    Chlorophytum comosum (Thunberg) Jacques
    Chlorophytum comosum (Thunberg) Jacques
    Cinnamomum camphora (L.) Siebold
    Cinnamomum camphora (L.) Siebold
    Colletia spinosissima J. F. Gmel.
    Colletia spinosissima J. F. Gmel.
    Cordyline australis (G.Forst.) Endl.
    Cordyline australis (G.Forst.) Endl.
    Cordyline australis (G.Forst.) Endl.
    Cornus capitata Wall. ex Roxb.
    Cortaderia selloana (Schult. & Schult. F.) Asch. & Graebn.
    Corylus avellana L.
    Cotoneaster salicifolius Franch.
    Cotoneaster salicifolius Franch.
    Crataegus monogyna Jacq.
    Crataegus monogyna Jacq.
    Cryptomeria japonica (L. filius) D. Don
    Cryptomeria japonica (L. filius) D. Don
    Cunninghamia lanceolata (Lamb.) Hook. f.
    Cunninghamia lanceolata (Lamb.) Hook. f.
    Cunninghamia lanceolata (Lamb.) Hook. f.
    Cupressus arizonica Greene
    Cupressus arizonica Greene
    Cupressus arizonica Greene
    Cupressus arizonica Greene
    Cupressus lusitanica Miller
    Cupressus lusitanica Miller
    Cupressus lusitanica Miller
    Cupressus lusitanica Miller
    Cupressus lusitanica Miller
    Dasylirion acrotrichum ((Schiede) Zucc.)
    Dasylirion acrotrichum ((Schiede) Zucc.)
    Dasylirion acrotrichum ((Schiede) Zucc.)
    Dasylirion acrotrichum ((Schiede) Zucc.)
    Deutzia crenata
    Deutzia crenata
    Deutzia crenata
    Deutzia crenata
    Deutzia crenata
    Dicksonia antarctica
    Diospyros kaki L.f.
    Erythrina lysistemon Thunb.
    Ginkgo biloba (L.)
    Ginkgo biloba (L.)
    Gleditsia triacanthos (L.)
    Jasminum officinalle (L.)
    Jasminum officinalle (L.)
    Jasminum officinalle (L.)
    Juglans regia (L.)
    Juglans regia (L.)
    Juniperus chinensis (L.)
    Juniperus chinensis (L.)
    Kalmia latifolia
    Laburnum anagyroides (Medic.
    Laburnum anagyroides (Medic.)
    Lagerstroemia indica (L.)
    Lagerstroemia indica (L.)
    Lantana camara (L.)
    Lantana camara (L.)
    Lantana camara (L.)
    Lantana camara (L.)
    Larix kaempferi (Lambert) Carriere
    Laurus nobilis L.
    Leucothoe fontanesiana (Steudel) Sleumer
    Leucothoe racemosa (L.) Gray
    Ligustrum lucidum Aiton fil.
    Ligustrum lucidum Aiton fil.
    Liquidambar styraciflua L.
    Liquidambar styraciflua L.
    Mahonia aquifolium (L.)
    Mahonia aquifolium (L.)
    Mahonia aquifolium (L.)
    Melia azedarach L.
    Melia azedarach L.
    Melia azedarach L.
    Melia azedarach L.
    Opuntia humifusa (Rafin.)
    Ostrya carpinifolia Scop.
    Ostrya carpinifolia Scop.
    Paulownia tomentosa (Thunb.) Steudel
    Paulownia tomentosa (Thunb.) Steudel
    Paulownia tomentosa (Thunb.) Steudel
    Paulownia tomentosa (Thunb.) Steudel
    Pavonia spinifex (L.) Cavanilles
    Pavonia spinifex (L.) Cavanilles
    Pavonia spinifex (L.) Cavanilles
    Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
    Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
    Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
    Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
    Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
    Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
    Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne
    Picea omorika (Pancic) Purkyne

Using the median as a pivot:

Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Abelia x grandiflora (Andre) Rehder
Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
Abies amabilis Dougl. Ex J. Forbes
Abies cephalonica Loudon
Abies cilicica (Ant. & kotchy) Carriere
Abies fraseri (Pursh) Poiret
Acacia nilotica (L.) Willd. ex Delile
Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
Acer japonicum Thunb.
Abies cephalonica Loudon
Abies cephalonica Loudon
Abies fraseri (Pursh) Poiret
Abies koreana Wilson
Abies koreana Wilson
Abies nordmanniana (Steven) Spach 1841.
Abies nordmanniana (Steven) Spach 1841.
Abies pinsapo Boisser
Acacia nilotica (L.) Willd. ex Delile
Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
Acacia retinodes Schlecht.
Acacia verticillata (L'Her.) Willd.
Acer buergerianum Miq.
Acer negundo L.
Acer palmatum Thunb.
Acer palmatum Thunb.
Acer pseudoplatanus L.
Acer rubrum L.
Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
Aesculus californica (Spach) Nutt.
Agave americana (L.)
Agave americana (L.)
Aloe vera (L.) Burm.F.
Aloe vera (L.) Burm.F.
Aloe vera (L.) Burm.F.
Araucaria angustifolia (Bertol.) Kuntze
Araucaria angustifolia (Bertol.) Kuntze
Callistemon linearis (DC.)
Camellia japonica (L.)
Carpinus japonica (Blume)
Catalpa x erubescens
Cercis siliquastrum L.
**Arbutus xalapensis Kunth**
**Arbutus xalapensis Kunth
Bischofia javanica Blume
Bischofia javanica Blume
Bischofia javanica Blume**
Caesalpinia echinata (Lam.)
Brugmansia sanguinea (Ruiz e Pav.) D. Don
Brugmansia sanguinea (Ruiz e Pav.) D. Don
Caesalpina spinosa (mol.) Kuntze
Caesalpina spinosa (mol.) Kuntze
Caesalpina spinosa (mol.) Kuntze
Calliandra tweedii (Benth.)
Calliandra tweedii (Benth.)
Callistemon linearis (DC.)
Callistemon linearis (DC.)
Callistemon linearis (DC.)
Calocedrus decurrens ((Torrey) Florin)
Calycanthus floridus (L.)
Carissa bispinosa ((L.) Desf. Ex Brenan)
```

B's aren't sorted when I use the median and some elements are out of place as well.

Comment: Not working Properly : any eror or not getting the required output , if working give some sample input and output ..

Comment: Working well if the pivot I choose is the left or the right element, not sorting well If I choose the median.

Comment: just add sample input and output .

Comment: Please read on how to post an MCVE : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Done, added an input and an output.

Comment: For median of three, take the median of leftmost, rightmost and middle, then swap it with the leftmost if not the leftmost.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use the standard `qsort()` function?  If there is, then you should still consider providing the same interface, and writing a comparison function separate from the sort.